# What is the origin of the suffix: 'ship'?

Tags: meaning, etymology

What is the origin of the suffix: 'ship'? 
Why was it chosen to become as a suffix ? 
What made it special over other words like maybe 'cart' or 'rainbow' or something?
    ie  friendSHIP might have been friendCART or friendRAINBOW
        penmanSHIP might have been penmanCART or penmanRAINBOW
Why was the word 'ship' chosen?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-ship), the suffix *-ship* is not the same as the noun *ship*. The suffix comes from the Old English word *sciappan* which means "to shape".

It is just a coincidence that in Modern English the suffix and the noun are the same. The noun *ship* comes from the Old English *scip*.